# Can I use my android as a wifi bridge via USB?

Tags: usb, internet, wifi-hotspot

I have a broadband connection to my computer, but no wireless router. I would like to know if I can connect my android as a wifi bridge; using my broadband connection instead of my mobile internet connection.

I am thinking of turning off mobile network, connecting my phone to my computer with a usb cable, selecting internet pass through, then turning on wifi hotspot.

Does this work, or will the phone default to the mobile internet connection instead?

I have icecream sandwich on an htc one x

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Setup the phone as a modem. Still most android phones can be setup as a WiFi hotspot.

Following URLs may help you

- http://benchmarkreviews.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=658&Itemid=38
- http://blogs.computerworld.com/smartphones/20726/android-wifi-hotspot