# What is the easiest way to create a wifi bridge from wifi router to PC through USB?

Tags: wi-fi, usb-tethering

I have a router with WiFi capability. The IP address of it is 192.168.1.1. Also the accepted IPs are in the range of 192.168.1.100-200. Now let's assume that I have no WiFi USB antenna for my PC. But I really want to be in the IP range of my WiFi router (e.g. the PC would have the address 192.168.1.110).

On my Android phone (in this case a older one, with Android 4.4.2 from HTC) I have the possibility to create USB tethering. (I also have root access on my phone). But the problem is, that the IP range from my phone through USB tethering is 192.168.42.x.

I could use something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=wifi%20bridge&num=100&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM68eYgMzaAhVI-6QKHcCeCwIQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=989), but I really want a solution with an Android phone!

I have an indirect solution to this:
For example my mobile phone has the IP address to the wifi router 192.168.1.100, and my PC has the IP address to my mobile phone through USB tethering 102.168.42.111. Now to connect to my PC, e.g. with the port 22 for an ssh connection, I must have a app for port forwarding on my phone. But this is too complicated.

Now my question: What can I do to achieve my goal? Or are there any Android apps which can do this automatically for me? (root or no root, it does not matter)

There is [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33297/can-i-use-my-android-as-a-wifi-bridge-via-usb) question, but it does not answer my question.

Edit: added the indirect solution to this.

Comment: It won't work... Hotspot and similar functions in Android act as a router, not a bridge. Honestly, just pickup a cheap WiFi dongle for the PC and enjoy.

Comment: So is there really no possibility to make a WiFi USB tethering bridge? Even when I am a root user? Is there really no app for something like that? I have a cheap WiFi dongle, but it is not stable plus also very slow.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... Making and Android bridge might be possible, but I've never heard of anyone doing it successfully on a phone. Perhaps a better dongle? I have a $10 N300 one that works great.